# Why does ! take me to a shell in mutt-kz?

Tags: linux, mutt

I'm running mutt-kz 1.5.23.1-5build1. The [Mutt documentation](http://dev.mutt.org/trac/wiki/MuttGuide/Folders) indicates that I should be able to return to my inbox with <kbd>!</kbd>, but I get prompted to type a shell command when I use <kbd>!</kbd> from within Mutt.

I could post my `.muttrc` here, but "!" and "shell" don't appear anywhere in it. Should I be reading different documentation? Is this something in Notmuch or specific to `mutt-kz`?

FWIW, `mutt-kz -v` gives me ...

```
amanda@giselle:~$ mutt-kz -v
Mutt 1.5.23.1 (2014-03-12)
Copyright (C) 1996-2009 Michael R. Elkins and others.
Mutt comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY; for details type `mutt -vv'.
Mutt is free software, and you are welcome to redistribute it
under certain conditions; type `mutt -vv' for details.

System: Linux 4.2.0-27-generic (x86_64)
ncurses: ncurses 5.9.20150516 (compiled with 5.9)
libidn: 1.28 (compiled with 1.28)
hcache backend: tokyocabinet 1.4.48
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I need to do <kbd>c</kbd><kbd>!</kbd> to get back to my inbox. Not just <kbd>!</kbd>.